# Can you customize Ktor 401 - Unauthorized Response?

Tags: kotlin, authentication, server, backend, ktor

When implementing [Basic Authentication](https://ktor.io/docs/basic.html) on Ktor and configuring a Provider, which validates whether the **credentials are legit by returning a non null** `Principal`, like in this example:

```
install(Authentication) {
    basic("auth-basic") {
        realm = "Access to the '/' path"
        validate { credentials ->
            if (credentials.name == "fernando" && credentials.password == "foobar") {
                UserIdPrincipal(credentials.name)
            } else {
                null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the credentials are invalid and a null is returned, then Ktor automatically communicates with the client by triggering a `401 - Unauthorized`, which in terms of behavior is what is expected...

**But I cannot provide/add any extra information, like for example where exactly the issue was: username or password.**

Any idea on how to mitigate this?

Comment: Did you try [StatusPages](https://ktor.io/docs/status-pages.html)?

Comment: This is probably related https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-2404

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips. I solved by using [StatusPages][1] plugin to respond appropriately to any failure state. 

Another tip is to not forget to pass in the same `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized`, cause otherwise your response will contain your object but will have `200` code.


  [1]: https://ktor.io/docs/status-pages.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for resolve this problem you can use **StatusPages** by install it on application calss.

like below:

```
install(StatusPages) {
    status(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) {
        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Your Response Object")
    }
}
```

for more informatin please read these links:
https://ktor.io/docs/status-pages.html
https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues/366

Answer (score 0):

The message when the token expires can be shown using [StatusPages](https://ktor.io/docs/status-pages.html) or by using the `challenge` method in the `JWTAuth` class like this:

```
jwt {
  challenge { _, _ ->
    call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Token is not valid or has expired")
  }
}
```